# Using the Filenames method of System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog returns System.String[]

Tags: powershell, batch-file, powershell-2.0, batch-processing

I'm new to Powershell and I am struggling with creating a script that'll return the file(s) chosen to the batch script I'm writing.

It's suppose to, when launched, open up a file browser where you can select multiple files and when the user confirms the selection, returns the file paths to the batch script.

This is what's in the batch file.

```
call :createPSscript
powershell -noprofile -noninteractive -executionpolicy unrestricted -Command "%~dp0FileSelector.ps1" >status
del FileSelector.ps1 >nul 2>&1
set /p status=<status
set /p queue=<queue
del status >nul 2>&1
echo %queue%
echo %status%
pause

:createPSscript
echo Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms>FileSelector.ps1
echo $openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog>>FileSelector.ps1
echo $openFileDialog.Title = "Select APK(s) to work with.">>FileSelector.ps1
echo $openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")>>FileSelector.ps1
echo $openFileDialog.Filter = "Android App Package (*.apk)|*.apk|All files (*.*)|*.*">>FileSelector.ps1
echo $openFileDialog.MultiSelect = $true>>FileSelector.ps1
echo $openFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true>>FileSelector.ps1
echo $openFileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = $true>>FileSelector.ps1
echo $openFileDialog.ShowDialog() > $null>>FileSelector.ps1
echo $stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "%~dp0queue">>FileSelector.ps1
echo 1 ^| %% $stream.WriteLine^($openFileDialog.Filenames^)>>FileSelector.ps1
echo $stream.close^(^)>>FileSelector.ps1
exit /b
```

And in the powershell script that the batch outputs to.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$openFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$openFileDialog.Title = "Select APK(s) to work with."
$openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = [Environment]::GetFolderPath("Desktop")
$openFileDialog.Filter = "Android App Package (*.apk)|*.apk|All files (*.*)|*.*"
$openFileDialog.MultiSelect = $true
$openFileDialog.ShowHelp = $true
$openFileDialog.AutoUpgradeEnabled = $true
$openFileDialog.ShowDialog() 
$stream = [System.IO.StreamWriter] "C:\Users\<redacted>\<redacted>\queue"
1 | % $stream.WriteLine($openFileDialog.Filenames)
$stream.close()
```

It works perfectly fine when I use $openFileDialog.Filename instead of $openFileDialog.Filename

%Status% returns if the user canceled or not and %queue% should return the list of files.

Did I do the syntax correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Annnnnnd I'm an idiot. Turns out just by invoking $openFileDialog.Filenames, it'll return the selected files to the output.